# Dism API - How to get the functions of the commandline tool

Tags: python, dism

I worked a lot with the documented DISM API and know all thier functions. I declared them one year ago in AutoIT and now in python but all the time i wondered why the commandline tool (type dism in cmd) has a lot of more functions provided.

Does someone know how to use these functions? For example, when i get an error, i can display it with DismGetLastErrorMessage, but the text comes in german. How can i get it in english? -> The commandline tool has a property called /English.
In the official Documentation is no option defined to change the language:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh824738.aspx

Here is a extended list of functions extracted of Dismapi.dll. http://windows10dll.nirsoft.net/dismapi_dll.html

There are some helper functions, which are not documented, but look like the commandline functions. Unhappily i don't know which parameter are required.